# How to filter UrlReferrer from a whitelist in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, app-config

I need to create a single page that is going to be a part of an existing ASP.NET MVC website that is only open or accessible if came from allowed websites (Referrer). Our partners are planning
to load this page using an iFrame. This page allows any user to quickly enter the details and save into
our database.

example: [www.mysecuredwebsite.com/publicpage](http://www.mysecuredwebsite.com/publicpage)

Since this is going to be public single page only and no logins, the only security is
only allow if the referrer is in the list of allowed sites.

Example:

1. [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)
2. [www.randomwebsite.com](http://www.randomwebsite.com)
3. [www.amazingsite.com](http://www.amazingsite.com)

Any request from any other sites will be redirected to an error page.

What is the best approach to this problem? I'm thinking of creating a custom attribute that will be used
to decorate the controller which then reads
a list of allowed sites from the app.config orany type of config.

Or maybe from the SQLDB since the site is using SQLDB? The list I think will be frequently change
depending on the growing number of clients. It should be easily configurable and does not require
redeployment.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use two methods

**Method 1:** Use `ActionFilterAttribute`.

**Method 2:** Use the `Application_BeginRequest` method in the `Global.asax` file.

**Note:** It is better to put the allowed urls in the database so that it can be easily changed.

I will explain the first method

> The following filter checks whether **UrlReferrer** is allowed. If it
> is not allowed, it will be referred to the error page.

add **UrlReferrerFilterAttribute**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace yournamespace
{
    public class UrlReferrerFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            string urlReferrer = string.Empty;
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
            {
                urlReferrer = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
                if(!db.UrlReferrerTable.Any(a => a.Url == urlReferrer))
                {
                    var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        action = "ErrorPage",
                        controller = "Home"
                    });
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);
                }
                
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

now use

```
[UrlReferrerFilter]
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
   //..................
   //..................
}
```